# Center node in zoomchart net chart

Tags: zoomcharts

By default when you double click on a node in zoomchart net chart, it moves to the center of the radial graph.  How to manually set any node to the center?

Answer (score 0):

use focusNodes mode and update initialNodes.

```
var t = new NetChart(
    {
        container: document.getElementById("demo"),
        area: { height: null },
        data: { randomNodes: 100},
        layout: {mode: "radial"},
        navigation: {mode: "focusnodes", focusNodeExpansionRadius: 10}
    }
);


function updateCenterNode(){
    var data = t.exportData(false);
    var node = data.nodes[Math.round(Math.random()*(data.nodes.length-1))];
    console.log(node.id);
    t.updateSettings(
        {
            navigation: {
                initialNodes: [node.id]
            }
        }
    );
}
```

setInterval(updateCenterNode, 3000);
jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rfyxchpg/